# Invoke a method of a JFrame from a JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

My question is how to to invoke a method of a `JFrame` from a `JInternalFrame`. I have the next class that extends from `JFrame`:

```
public class VentanaPaint extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/**
 * Creates new form VentanaPaint
 */
public VentanaPaint() {
    initComponents();
}


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    GroupButtonNav = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup2PaletaColores = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    barraNavegacion = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
    BotonDibujarPunto = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JToolBar.Separator();
    BotonDibujarLinea = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    BotonDibujarCuadrado = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    BotonDibujarElipse = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    contenedorEscritorio = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    escritorio = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
    panelBarraTrabajo = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    panelBarraHerramientas = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    contenedorPaletaColores = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    PaletaColores = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    botonNegro = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    botonRojo = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    botonAzul = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    botonBlanco = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    botonAmarillo = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    botonVerde = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    contendorGrosor = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    spinnerGrosor = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
    contenedorOpciones = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jCheckBoxEditar = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jCheckBoxRelleno = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jCheckBoxAlisar = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    checkBoxTransparencia = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    panelBarraNotificacion = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    barraNotificacion = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jMenuBar2 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    Archivo = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Nuevo = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    abrirArchivo = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    guardarArchivo = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    Edicion = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    BarraEstado = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();

    FormListener formListener = new FormListener();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 252, 240));

    barraNavegacion.setRollover(true);

    GroupButtonNav.add(BotonDibujarPunto);
    BotonDibujarPunto.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/practica7/pics/lapiz2_24x24.png"))); // NOI18N
    BotonDibujarPunto.setFocusable(false);
    BotonDibujarPunto.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    BotonDibujarPunto.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    BotonDibujarPunto.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(62, 62));
    BotonDibujarPunto.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(62, 62));
    BotonDibujarPunto.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(20, 20));
    BotonDibujarPunto.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    BotonDibujarPunto.addMouseListener(formListener);
    barraNavegacion.add(BotonDibujarPunto);
    barraNavegacion.add(jSeparator1);

    GroupButtonNav.add(BotonDibujarLinea);
    BotonDibujarLinea.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/practica7/pics/line24x24.png"))); // NOI18N
    BotonDibujarLinea.setFocusable(false);
    BotonDibujarLinea.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    BotonDibujarLinea.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    BotonDibujarLinea.addMouseListener(formListener);
    barraNavegacion.add(BotonDibujarLinea);

    GroupButtonNav.add(BotonDibujarCuadrado);
    BotonDibujarCuadrado.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/practica7/pics/cuadrado24x24.png"))); // NOI18N
    BotonDibujarCuadrado.setFocusable(false);
    BotonDibujarCuadrado.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    BotonDibujarCuadrado.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    BotonDibujarCuadrado.addMouseListener(formListener);
    barraNavegacion.add(BotonDibujarCuadrado);

    GroupButtonNav.add(BotonDibujarElipse);
    BotonDibujarElipse.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/practica7/pics/elipse24x24.png"))); // NOI18N
    BotonDibujarElipse.setFocusable(false);
    BotonDibujarElipse.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    BotonDibujarElipse.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    BotonDibujarElipse.addMouseListener(formListener);
    barraNavegacion.add(BotonDibujarElipse);

    getContentPane().add(barraNavegacion, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

    contenedorEscritorio.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    javax.swing.GroupLayout escritorioLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(escritorio);
    escritorio.setLayout(escritorioLayout);
    escritorioLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        escritorioLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 478, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    escritorioLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        escritorioLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 149, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    contenedorEscritorio.add(escritorio, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    getContentPane().add(contenedorEscritorio, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panelBarraTrabajo.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    panelBarraHerramientas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 208, 182));
    panelBarraHerramientas.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
    java.awt.FlowLayout flowLayout1 = new java.awt.FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.LEFT, 15, 5);
    flowLayout1.setAlignOnBaseline(true);
    panelBarraHerramientas.setLayout(flowLayout1);

    contenedorPaletaColores.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 208, 182));
    contenedorPaletaColores.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Colores"));

    PaletaColores.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    PaletaColores.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(320, 320));
    PaletaColores.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(129, 58));
    PaletaColores.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(2, 3));

    botonNegro.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    buttonGroup2PaletaColores.add(botonNegro);
    botonNegro.addMouseListener(formListener);
    PaletaColores.add(botonNegro);

    botonRojo.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    buttonGroup2PaletaColores.add(botonRojo);
    botonRojo.addMouseListener(formListener);
    PaletaColores.add(botonRojo);

    botonAzul.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
    buttonGroup2PaletaColores.add(botonAzul);
    botonAzul.addMouseListener(formListener);
    PaletaColores.add(botonAzul);

    botonBlanco.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    buttonGroup2PaletaColores.add(botonBlanco);
    botonBlanco.addMouseListener(formListener);
    PaletaColores.add(botonBlanco);

    botonAmarillo.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));
    buttonGroup2PaletaColores.add(botonAmarillo);
    botonAmarillo.addMouseListener(formListener);
    PaletaColores.add(botonAmarillo);

    botonVerde.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 51));
    buttonGroup2PaletaColores.add(botonVerde);
    botonVerde.addMouseListener(formListener);
    PaletaColores.add(botonVerde);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout contenedorPaletaColoresLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(contenedorPaletaColores);
    contenedorPaletaColores.setLayout(contenedorPaletaColoresLayout);
    contenedorPaletaColoresLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        contenedorPaletaColoresLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(PaletaColores, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );
    contenedorPaletaColoresLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        contenedorPaletaColoresLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(PaletaColores, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    panelBarraHerramientas.add(contenedorPaletaColores);

    contendorGrosor.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 208, 182));
    contendorGrosor.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Grosor"));
    contendorGrosor.setName(""); // NOI18N
    contendorGrosor.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 12));

    spinnerGrosor.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(Float.valueOf(0.0f), Float.valueOf(0.0f), Float.valueOf(40.0f), Float.valueOf(1.0f)));
    spinnerGrosor.addChangeListener(formListener);
    contendorGrosor.add(spinnerGrosor);

    panelBarraHerramientas.add(contendorGrosor);

    contenedorOpciones.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 208, 182));
    contenedorOpciones.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
    contenedorOpciones.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(2, 2));

    jCheckBoxEditar.setText("Editar");
    jCheckBoxEditar.addChangeListener(formListener);
    contenedorOpciones.add(jCheckBoxEditar);

    jCheckBoxRelleno.setText("Relleno");
    jCheckBoxRelleno.addChangeListener(formListener);
    contenedorOpciones.add(jCheckBoxRelleno);

    jCheckBoxAlisar.setText("Alisar");
    jCheckBoxAlisar.addChangeListener(formListener);
    contenedorOpciones.add(jCheckBoxAlisar);

    checkBoxTransparencia.setText("Transparencia");
    checkBoxTransparencia.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    checkBoxTransparencia.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    checkBoxTransparencia.addChangeListener(formListener);
    contenedorOpciones.add(checkBoxTransparencia);

    panelBarraHerramientas.add(contenedorOpciones);

    panelBarraTrabajo.add(panelBarraHerramientas, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panelBarraNotificacion.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    panelBarraNotificacion.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    barraNotificacion.setText("  ");
    panelBarraNotificacion.add(barraNotificacion, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panelBarraTrabajo.add(panelBarraNotificacion, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    getContentPane().add(panelBarraTrabajo, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    Archivo.setText("Archivo");

    Nuevo.setText("Nuevo");
    Nuevo.addMouseListener(formListener);
    Archivo.add(Nuevo);

    abrirArchivo.setText("Abrir");
    abrirArchivo.addActionListener(formListener);
    Archivo.add(abrirArchivo);

    guardarArchivo.setText("Guardar");
    guardarArchivo.addActionListener(formListener);
    Archivo.add(guardarArchivo);

    jMenuBar2.add(Archivo);

    Edicion.setText("Edición");

    BarraEstado.setSelected(true);
    BarraEstado.setText("Ver barra de estado");
    BarraEstado.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    BarraEstado.addActionListener(formListener);
    Edicion.add(BarraEstado);

    jMenuBar2.add(Edicion);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar2);

    pack();
}

// Code for dispatching events from components to event handlers.

private class FormListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener, java.awt.event.MouseListener, javax.swing.event.ChangeListener {
    FormListener() {}
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == abrirArchivo) {
            VentanaPaint.this.abrirArchivoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == guardarArchivo) {
            VentanaPaint.this.guardarArchivoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == BarraEstado) {
            VentanaPaint.this.BarraEstadoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == BotonDibujarPunto) {
            VentanaPaint.this.BotonDibujarPuntoMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == BotonDibujarLinea) {
            VentanaPaint.this.BotonDibujarLineaMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == BotonDibujarCuadrado) {
            VentanaPaint.this.BotonDibujarCuadradoMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == BotonDibujarElipse) {
            VentanaPaint.this.BotonDibujarElipseMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == botonNegro) {
            VentanaPaint.this.botonNegroMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == botonRojo) {
            VentanaPaint.this.botonRojoMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == botonAzul) {
            VentanaPaint.this.botonAzulMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == botonBlanco) {
            VentanaPaint.this.botonBlancoMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == botonAmarillo) {
            VentanaPaint.this.botonAmarilloMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == botonVerde) {
            VentanaPaint.this.botonVerdeMouseClicked(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == Nuevo) {
            VentanaPaint.this.NuevoMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    }

    public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == spinnerGrosor) {
            VentanaPaint.this.spinnerGrosorStateChanged(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == jCheckBoxEditar) {
            VentanaPaint.this.jCheckBoxEditarStateChanged(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == jCheckBoxRelleno) {
            VentanaPaint.this.jCheckBoxRellenoStateChanged(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == jCheckBoxAlisar) {
            VentanaPaint.this.jCheckBoxAlisarStateChanged(evt);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource() == checkBoxTransparencia) {
            VentanaPaint.this.checkBoxTransparenciaStateChanged(evt);
        }
    }
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void guardarArchivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
JFileChooser dlg = new JFileChooser();
int resp = dlg.showSaveDialog(this);
    if( resp == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          File f = dlg.getSelectedFile();
          //codigo;
    }
}
```

Here I create a new `JInternalFrame`:

```
private void NuevoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //le pasamos el padre
    VentanaInterna vi=new VentanaInterna(this);
    escritorio.add(vi);
    vi.setVisible(true);
}                                  


public JToolBar getBarraNavegacion(){
    return barraNavegacion;

}

public void setBarraNavegacion(JToolBar nuevaBarraNavegacion)
{
    barraNavegacion=nuevaBarraNavegacion;
}

public javax.swing.JSpinner getSpinnerGrosor(){
    return spinnerGrosor;
}



// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu Archivo;
private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem BarraEstado;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton BotonDibujarCuadrado;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton BotonDibujarElipse;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton BotonDibujarLinea;
public javax.swing.JToggleButton BotonDibujarPunto;
private javax.swing.JMenu Edicion;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup GroupButtonNav;
private javax.swing.JMenu Nuevo;
private javax.swing.JPanel PaletaColores;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem abrirArchivo;
public javax.swing.JToolBar barraNavegacion;
private javax.swing.JLabel barraNotificacion;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton botonAmarillo;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton botonAzul;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton botonBlanco;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton botonNegro;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton botonRojo;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton botonVerde;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2PaletaColores;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox checkBoxTransparencia;
private javax.swing.JPanel contendorGrosor;
private javax.swing.JPanel contenedorEscritorio;
private javax.swing.JPanel contenedorOpciones;
private javax.swing.JPanel contenedorPaletaColores;
private javax.swing.JDesktopPane escritorio;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem guardarArchivo;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBoxAlisar;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBoxEditar;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBoxRelleno;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar2;
private javax.swing.JToolBar.Separator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelBarraHerramientas;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelBarraNotificacion;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelBarraTrabajo;
private javax.swing.JSpinner spinnerGrosor;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

And from the next class, inside the method

```
private void formInternalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt)
```

I want to access the `padre` of the `JFrame` variables.
How can I access these variables?

```
public class VentanaInterna extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
//public practica7.Lienzo2D lienzo;
public javax.swing.JFrame padre;

public VentanaInterna() {
    initComponents();
    padre=new javax.swing.JFrame();
}
/**
 * Creates new form VentanaInterna
 * @param nuevoPadre
 */
public VentanaInterna(javax.swing.JFrame  nuevoPadre) {
    initComponents();
    padre=new javax.swing.JFrame();
    padre=nuevoPadre;
}

/**
 * metodo selector que devuele el padre
 * @return padre
 */
public javax.swing.JFrame  getPadre()
{
    return padre;
}

/**
 * metodo modificador que modifica el padre
 * @param padrenuevo
 */
public  void setPadre(javax.swing.JFrame  padrenuevo )
{
    padre=padrenuevo;
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    lienzo1 = new practica7.Lienzo2D();

    setClosable(true);
    setIconifiable(true);
    setMaximizable(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setTitle("Nuevo lienzo");
    addInternalFrameListener(new javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener() {
        public void internalFrameOpened(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameClosing(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameClosed(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameIconified(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameDeiconified(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            formInternalFrameActivated(evt);
        }
        public void internalFrameDeactivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(lienzo1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 324, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(lienzo1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 224, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void formInternalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    /*
   Component c[]= padre.getRootPane().getComponents();
   for(Component comp:c){
       if((comp.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName())=="BotonDibujarPunto"){
           comp.
       }

   }
   */
}                                           


 // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
 private practica7.Lienzo2D lienzo1;
 // End of variables declaration                   
public practica7.Lienzo2D getLienzo()
{
return lienzo1;
}

}//final clase
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> i want to acces jFrame "padre" variables. How can I acces to these variable?

I'm going to suggest that you in fact *don't* want to do this since it is dangerous to have one class directly manipulating the fields of another without any oversight or control whatsoever as this increases code coupling, not a good thing to do. Instead make sure that the VentanaPaint class has public *methods* that outside classes can call and that change its state but in a way that it itself can control (and even disallow if necessary).

Since your VentanaInterna class already has a padre field, one that has been assigned a viable reference to the currently displayed VentanaPaint JFrame, then these methods should be easy to call.

---

Also, to access VentanaPaint-specific calls, change the type of the padre field to VentanaPaint rather than JFrame. For example change this:

```
public class VentanaInterna extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
public javax.swing.JFrame padre;

public VentanaInterna(javax.swing.JFrame  nuevoPadre) {
    initComponents();
    // padre=new javax.swing.JFrame();??? don't do this
    padre=nuevoPadre;
}
```

to this:

```
public class VentanaInterna extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
public VentanaPaint padre;

public VentanaInterna(VentanaPaint nuevoPadre) {
    initComponents();
    // padre=new javax.swing.JFrame();??? don't do this
    padre=nuevoPadre;
}
```

Comment: yes ,I have  public javax.swing.JSpinner getSpinnerGrosor(){
    return spinnerGrosor;
} which is public .but i don't know how to acces to this method from padre which reference JFrame

Comment: @BogdanMuresan: ah yes, I see. Your problem is simply one of changing the type of a variable. Please see edit to answer.